# hyper-v install OS programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, installation, automation, hyper-v

Let's say I have ISO of some Windows OS and I want to do something like to create virtual machine on hyper-v, mount ISO to it and install system. Then on installed system to run some commands via powershell, cmd like activating the system, assign ip address and so on... So my question is: Can I somehow install OS, lets say Windows 10, on Hyper-V server programmatically using C#?

Would there be some problem with the installation? Do I need some special ISO/config that the installation would not require any user input like cd-key, choosing where to install the system, creating user and other settings?

I have no code yet, I only looked at hyper-v API. I am just trying to find out if is this even possible to automatize this process.

Comment: Automation of installing Windows is possible, but I think cloning from an installed Windows image is easier. never tried to use Hyper-V API though

Comment: Also interested in this, I've been searching for a way to automate a Hyper-V linux installation with no luck. I'll bookmark this and bring any info back that I find.